# Why is it idiomatic to write `Html msg` instead of `Html a`?

Tags: elm

I'm a beginner to Elm. This is a question about style, not how something works.

For example, in http://elm-lang.org/examples/form we have

`viewValidation : Model -> Html msg`

I know this is done so that `viewValidation model` can coexist in the same list as values of type `Html Msg`. But, since `msg` here is just a type variable, why not use the more traditional `a`?

What extra information is `msg` intended to convey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elm Architecture encourages consistent naming of types like `Model` and `Msg` to convey their meaning. The use of lowercase `msg` just makes it a little more clear what the intention is.

It very well could have been named `a`, but that arguably doesn't convey as much information.

**Edit**

To elaborate a bit more, consider the documentation for the [`elm-lang/html`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html) package.

Let's take a look at the definition of [`Html.program`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#program):

```elm
program :
    { init : (model, Cmd msg)
    , update : msg -> model -> (model, Cmd msg)
    , subscriptions : model -> Sub msg
    , view : model -> Html msg
    } -> Program Never model msg
```

[The Elm Architecture](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/) outlines very clear intentions of how your `Model` and `Msg` types are to be used by the framework to carry state and indicate what actions are to be performed. By using lowercase `msg` and `model` consistently through the documentation, it becomes much easier to understand what goes where.

Consider the alternative of a more Haskellesque approach where the type parameters are often abbreviated starting at `a`:

```elm
program :
    { init : (a, Cmd b)
    , update : b -> a -> (a, Cmd b)
    , subscriptions : a -> Sub b
    , view : a -> Html b
    } -> Program Never a b
```

That definition is every bit as valid, but I would argue that it is not nearly as explanatory as the documentation for `program`, which offers strong hints about where your `Msg` and `Model` types are to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you be more explicit about what the extra information conveyed is?

Comment: I've updated the above answer with a little more information using examples from the documentation.

Comment: Ah, I see. So `msg` means "this should probably be a value of type `Msg`, however that's defined in your program". If `Msg` was not defined by the user but rather imported from this library, the type would be `Html Msg` instead of `Html msg`. Do you think that's a fair summary?

Comment: That sounds like an adequate summary